# Can we send notification globally without using firebase?

Tags: android, rest, firebase, android-notifications

Can we create rest services for sending a notification to Android app without using Firebase Cloud Messaging / Google Cloud Messaging or other cloud messenger tool? If yes, how's that possible? I have searched for the same but couldn't get the appropriate result. The result I get in that REST services are combined with cloud messenger tool, but I want to create services through which I could easily send notification without open Cloud Messenger console.

**code to handle data from php**

```
    private void handleNotification(String message) {
    Log.e(TAG, "===========================messaging 4=======" );

    if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {

        Intent intent= new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("message",message);
        intent.putExtra("imageUrl",imageUrl);
        intent.putExtra("time_stamp",timeStamp);

        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);


        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);

        final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);


        Uri notificationSound= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notifiBuilder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("NOTIFICATION !!")
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(notificationSound)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent) ;

        NotificationManager notificationManager=
                ( NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0,notifiBuilder.build());


        Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
        pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

        // play notification sound
       /* NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());

       notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();*/


    }
}

private void handleDataMessage(JSONObject json) {
    Log.e(TAG, "===========================messaging 4=======" );
    Log.e(TAG, "push json: " + json.toString());


    try {
        JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");

        String title = data.getString("title");
        String message = data.getString("message");
       boolean isBackground = data.getBoolean("is_background");
        String imageUrl = data.getString("image");
       String timestamp = data.getString("timestamp");
      JSONObject payload = data.getJSONObject("payload");

        Log.e(TAG, "title: " + title);
        Log.e(TAG, "message: " + message);
       Log.e(TAG, "isBackground: " + isBackground);
        Log.e(TAG, "payload: " + payload.toString());
        Log.e(TAG, "imageUrl: " + imageUrl);
        Log.e(TAG, "timestamp: " + timestamp);


        if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
            // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message

            Intent intent= new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
            final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);


            Uri notificationSound= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

            NotificationCompat.Builder notifiBuilder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("NOTIFICATION data message!!")
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .addAction(R.mipmap.ic_accept,"ACCEPT",pendingIntent)
                    .addAction(R.mipmap.ic_decline,"DECLINE",pendingIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(notificationSound)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent) ;

            NotificationManager notificationManager=
                    ( NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            notificationManager.notify(0,notifiBuilder.build());


            Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
            pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

            // play notification sound

        } else {
            // app is in background, show the notification in notification tray

            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            resultIntent.putExtra("message", message);

            // check for image attachment
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {
                showNotificationMessage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, resultIntent);
            } else {
                // image is present, show notification with image
                showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, resultIntent, imageUrl);
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Json Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Using gcm or fcm you do not have to open the console to send messages. You can send a json http requests to their server and they will handle the rest. See the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref)

Comment: I have read the documentation but still didn't get my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be a longer and tough process

1. Create a background service in your app which keeps on checking your webserver for new messages after every certain interval(May be seconds or Minutes).
2. This service is liable to be killed or cleaned by the Android OS. Hence, you may need to register an AlarmManager which invokes the Services at the intervals.
3. The background service, will call a webserver API along with a unique ID (May be device ID or some Access Token)
4. On your webserver, you can create an API which, on receiving a request from the device, using the passed UniqueID, checks if there is any message or not. If there is a message, it responds back with the data.
5. On the App, on receiving the data from the webserver, you can do the needful.

A similar process is used by FCM/GCM. But it guarantees the notification, as the GooglePlayServices is always running in Android in the background.

This procedure can make you do what you want to a certain extent, but, as aforesaid, can be difficult and challenging.

Comment: could you please help me with program for the same ? you can do share code on my email id too. @Atish Agrawal

Comment: @exampleone I can help you. The whole StackOverflow community is here for your help. Please show us what you have done and what you are trying to achieve so that we can help.

Comment: I want to send notification to android app,without using firebase console. for that I used php as backend. I run my php code and got result  success:1 but still not getting notification. Moreover **Json Exception: Value {"image":"","is_background":false,"title":"hey all","message":"demo","timestamp":"2017-07-27 12:22:41"} at data of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject** getting this error in logcat

Comment: @exampleone Please check your code where you are creating a JSONObject object from the string. You are doing something wrong. This doesn't have anything to do with the PHP Backend or Firebase

Answer (score 0):

Since GCM uses simple TCP connection you can do it by urself.

All you need is single TCP Server and TCP client on every device you need.

Will be almost the same, but it will consume more battery.

Comment: previously I was  sending notification using Firebase, can it be achieve by REST services?

Comment: You can, but that will be not so good. For example you can send request from client to ask if you have new message for current client every N sec/min.